# Mac had High Sierra, had to install Lion from Internet Recovery into a new hard drive, can't install High Sierra

Tags: macos, upgrade, high-sierra

I had Mac OS High Sierra on my laptop. I have had some errors on my laptop's hard drive. I bought an SSD and had to install Mac OS Lion from Internet Recovery. I see ads for a free Mac OS High Sierra upgrade, but it says I need Mac OS 10.8 or later (I have 10.7.x installed). How can I get back to Mac OS High Sierra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Launch the Mac App Store app
2. Select the Purchased tab
3. Look through your purchased items to find OS X Mountain Lion (**Note:** There's nothing stopping you from also selecting either OS X Mavericks or OS X El Capitan)
4. Now click on the Download option on the right of the listing

This will download the OS X installer allowing you to upgrade from OS X Lion. Once you're upgraded, you'll then have the option/ability to upgrade to macOS High Sierra.

**NOTE:** If you can't see your Purchased list, or download the item, make sure you're actually signed into your account (i.e. look under the Store menu).

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12 goes to Mac OS El Capitan, I can download this and then install High Sierra.

Comment: *(comment re-done to fix appalling typos affecting comprehensibility ;)* The version of El Cap you see on the regular store will only install to Macs that cannot run any higher OS. You need to use one from your purchase history.